# Avoid SharePoint default error screen

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow

I'm developing custom component for SharePoint and when I get some errors I get from SharePoint the default error screen. Is there a way to avoid it and get the IIS asp error instead?
Moreover, are SharePoint Logs the only place to get more information about errors and exceptions?

Thank you, bye bye...

Answer (score 2):

What version of SharePoint are you using?

If you're using SharePoint 2010, you can enable the Developer Dashboard to get access to debug information, including trace logs.  See http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/28/using-the-developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

You can also enable ASP.NET Tracing in your web.config file (be careful) to get trace information about the error.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If under "some errors" you mean access denied cases you need to turn off default handling that redirects to "sign in as other user" page. See CatchAccessDeniedException (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.catchaccessdeniedexception.aspx)